# How to intercept 3-way handshake on LAN using linux terminal without tcpdump and wireshark?

Tags: linux, networking, tcp

I have no root access, I have no access to any graphical software (I would love to use wireshark), and I can't install tcpdump and any other tool because of no privileges.

I've been looking for some good alternatives but without luck. Are there might be any preinstalled tools, tricks or absolutely anything that could help me do this? What can I do to make it possible? The OS I work on its ironically kali, maximally truncated one as you can see.

Comment: you can list open sockets (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17523389/check-all-socket-opened-in-linux-os/17523444)). there is also tcp_probe, although based on comments in the answer i don't know why would a user without priviledges be able to load kernel modules.

Comment: I did what you proposed, no results. I have found two machines, the sender and receiver and I got their IP addresses. Can this help me somehow to do what I wanted? I tried so many tools, that I feel like im running out of ideas.

Comment: what exactly do you need to do with the intercepted handshake?

Answer (score 2):

The whole idea of privileges (like superuser privileges, or in your case, more fine-grained capabilities to monitor network interfaces) is that a normal user *cannot* do what you want to do.

So, unless there's an acute severe security bug that the rest of the world has been missing (or the computer you've got access to hasn't had any security fixes in a **very** long time), you simply can't. The kernel won't give you access to do that.

That's by design.

Comment: Ok, but does anything logs the network traffic and activity? Maybe I could find some past handshakes, not exactly capture the live ones?

Comment: only if that has a security hole would you be able to access these logs (notice a pattern here: security by not giving you access you shouldn't have to information about other people's traffic!). Also, no, unless this is a surveillance device, why should it log traffic?

Comment: It looked silly from the beginning even for a novice like me - no tools, no privileges, anything. "Find a message that has been sent over TCP during 3-way handshake", looks like I was given an impossible mission. Thank you for your help and confirming to not waste my time on this.